# insert nested fields in mongodb collection using python

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I am new to mongoDb and looking for some help  in **inserting nested values to mongoldb collection using python.**

I Have a collection in mongoDB called(test) that already has a number of fields in it..and looks something like this

```
[0:

{
A:1,

B:5,

C:10,

D:

{
   F1: 67

   F2: 54
 }

},

1: {

A:3

B:8

C:100,

D:{

   F1: 60,

   F2: 4,
 }}
,

2:{

A:15,

B:51,

C:100,

D:{

   F1: 97

   F2: 32
 }

}]
```

Now I created some new fields in a python scripts that generates some value for each index,This is the result json that I have for each index:

```
{0:

   {Newfield:
       
        {nested field:{ 

                            Value1: 6,

                            Value 2: 8,

                            Value 3: 11,

                           }

      }
1: {Newfield:
       
        {nested field:{ 

                            Value1: 64,

                            Value 2: 83,

                            Value 3: 21,

                           }

      }
2: {Newfield:
       
        {nested field:{ 

                            Value1: 89,

                            Value 2: 65,

                            Value 3: 34,

                           }

      }
}
```

now I want to add these fields to this existing collection, so the new collection would look something like this:

```
[0: {
     A:1,

B:5,

C:10,

D:{

   F1: 67

   F2: 54
 }

Newfield:

       {nested field:{ 

                            Value1: 6,

                            Value 2: 8,

                            Value 3: 11,

                           }


      }
}
,

1: {

A:3

B:8

C:100,

D:{

   F1: 60,

   F2: 4,

   }

Newfield:

       {nested field:{ 

                            Value1: 64,

                            Value 2: 83,

                            Value 3: 21,

                           }

      }
,

2:{

A:15,

B:51,

C:100,

D:{

   F1: 97

   F2: 32

 }

Newfield:

       {nested field:{ 

                            Value1: 89,

                            Value 2: 65,

                            Value 3: 34,

                           }

      }

}]
```

There a multiple rows in original collection and result so I am looking for a for loop or something that creates the nested field and then populates it with json result file for each row.
Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Would you clarify what your collection is, what you documents are, and format them so it's easy to see what you have and what you want?  It's not clear if you are showing array indices, or some kind of document numbering, etc.  For example, is your `test` collection like [shown here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pWSSZZGarlQ "Link to mongoplayground.net -->")?

Comment: It's a json collection of strings and numbers...and the nested Feilds I want to add is also a json result.

Comment: It's still not clear what you are showing. Are you showing 3 collection documents?... An array within a single document? Are the new nested field values derived from the other values in the document?